# Formatting the query params using Axios

Tags: axios, xero-api

According to Xero API [doc](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/invoices/#get-invoices):

| **Field** | **Description** |
| --- | --- |
| **Record filter** | You can specify an individual record by appending the value to the endpoint, i.e. GET https://.../Invoices/{identifier} InvoiceID - The Xero identifier for an Invoice e.g. 297c2dc5-cc47-4afd-8ec8-74990b8761e9 InvoiceNumber - The InvoiceNumber e.g. INV-01514 |
| **Modified After** | The ModifiedAfter filter is actually an HTTP header: ' If-Modified-Since'. A UTC timestamp (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss) . Only invoices created or modified since this timestamp will be returned e.g. 2009-11-12T00:00:00 |
| **IDs, InvoiceNumbers, ContactIDs, Statuses** | Filter by a comma-separated list of InvoicesIDs, InvoiceNumbers, ContactIDs or Statuses. See details. |
| **Where** | Filter using the where parameter. We recommend you limit filtering to the optimised elements only. |
| **createdByMyApp** | When set to true you'll only retrieve Invoices created by your app |
| **order** | Order by any element returned ( see Order By ) |
| **page** | Up to 100 invoices will be returned per call, with line items shown for each, when the page parameter is used e.g. page=1 |
| **summaryOnly** | When set to true, this returns lightweight fields, excluding computation-heavy fields from the response, making the API calls quick and efficient. |

My request is constructed like so:

```
const params = {
  'Statuses': 'AUTHORISED,PAID',
  'page': 1,
  'summaryOnly': false,
}
const config = {
  headers: { 'If-Modified-Since': '2015-01-01T00:00:00' }
}
instance.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  console.log('Starting Request', request)
  return request;
});
const response = await instance.get('Invoices', params, config);
const data = response.data;
```

... but none of the params seem to be taking effect as the request log shows:

```
{
  transitional: {
    silentJSONParsing: true,
    forcedJSONParsing: true,
    clarifyTimeoutError: false
  },
  ...
  headers: AxiosHeaders {
    Authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZC...',
    [Symbol(defaults)]: { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*' }
  },
  baseURL: 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/',
  Statuses: 'AUTHORISED,PAID',
  page: 1,
  summaryOnly: false,
  method: 'get',
  url: 'Invoices'
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the params in the config object itself.

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
axios
  .get(url, {
    params: {
      hello: 1,
    },
    headers: {
      myHeader: 123,
    },
  })
```

In your case, you can do the following:

```js
const params = {
  'Statuses': 'AUTHORISED,PAID',
  'page': 1,
  'summaryOnly': false,
}

const config = {
  params,
  headers: { 'If-Modified-Since': '2015-01-01T00:00:00' }
}
// rest of your code
```

Here is the [documentation reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#request-config)